# Installing Ubuntu on Acer Aspire V5-573G-54208G50AKK: nothing happens

Tags: system-installation, acer

I have this brand new Acer Aspire v5-573g-54208g50akk laptop. I started the preinstalled Windows 8 and then changed the boot priority to USB. But right after I choose *Install Ubuntu* or *Try Ubuntu* on the menu screen, the screen goes black and nothing happens.

I used Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.4.5 to create a bootable USB stick. I used this program on a different laptop before and it worked.

I tried different USB Sticks

I tried Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Ubuntu 13.10

Nothing helped :/

Comment: Take a look at this answer [http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/223798][1].
Especially the nomodeset part.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/223798

Comment: it looks promising, but it doesnt work. i dont think it is only a graphic card disfunction. because the keyboard backlight on the laptop does out too and the internal hdd goes out. it looks like the laptop shut down except that its power led suggests that its still on.. :/

Answer (score 0):

try [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for writing image into USB, I had some similar problems while using other applications.

Comment: well.. unetbootin does not display any my of flash drives where i could put my ubutunu image. and harddrives only "c:" .. :( help-section of its website doesnt help at all

Comment: unetbootin seems to have problems finding flash drives. event if they are formatted correctly. tried to google it, many problems, no fixes

Comment: it might be UEFI related problem [read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: i have a new usb stick, unetbootin seems to work on it. ill give it another try..

Answer (score 0):

Before hitting the Button "Install Ubuntu"

1. Press F6
2. Choose "nomodeset"

now it should Install, after installing you have also to enter it in the GRUB.

You can find both here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132